# Adding testng dependency on maven module with jUnit causes " There was an error in the forked process"

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, junit, testng

I have a maven module which runs jUnit tests which obviously means that junit is added as a dependency.

For some reasons, i need to add a dependency, which in turn depends on testng jar. If I do this, I get an error when I do a mvn verify

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project arm: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/IClassListener
[ERROR]         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
[ERROR]         at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
[ERROR]         at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
[ERROR]         at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
[ERROR]         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
[ERROR]         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
[ERROR]         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
[ERROR]         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[ERROR]         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
[ERROR]         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[ERROR]         at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
[ERROR]         at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:370)
[ERROR]         at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
[ERROR]         at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
[ERROR]         at org.testng.TestNG.addServiceLoaderListeners(TestNG.java:956)
[ERROR]         at org.testng.TestNG.initializeConfiguration(TestNG.java:891)
[ERROR]         at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1005)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:115)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeMulti(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:205)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:108)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:111)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.IClassListener
[ERROR]         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
[ERROR]         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[ERROR]         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
[ERROR]         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[ERROR]         ... 27 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "in turn depends on testng jar"? How exactly depends? Did you try to add testng as a dependency (with "test" scope)? Including a snipped with the dependencies in your question could help.

Comment: Can you post your `pom.xml`?